# count number of ocurrences in a year in a particular field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have strings like `FVS101209GO5` Stored in a MS Access data table, I want to count the number of strings in a certain year, so in the example that would be the year 2010

I was doing

```
query = "SELECT SUM( IIF( Mid( KEYLastName, 4, 2) , 1,0)) AS occur FROM MyTable WHERE Year(mydate)=2010 ;"
```

The length of the string is 12 or 13, for the examples @JW added

```
qwe123456XXX       -  2012
asd345678XXX       -  2034  
FVS101209GO5       -  2010
```

Comment: canyou give your desired result, eg if you have records like this,`qwert123`, `asd345`, `FVS101209GO5`, what will be the output then?

Comment: Use `GROUP BY`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to find the count of occurrences of various years within a string, you might like to use:

```
SELECT Mid([KEYLastName],4,2) AS [Year], 
       Count(KEYLastName) AS CountOfOccurances
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Mid([KEYLastName],4,2)
```

This will return all the two digit years at (4,2) and the number of times they each occur.

Edit re Comments

```
SELECT KEYLastName, 
       Mid([KEYLastName],4,2) AS [Year], 
       DCount("*","MyTable","Mid([KEYLastName],4,2)=" 
          & Mid([KEYLastName],4,2)) AS YearCount
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: This is very helpful, is there a way to add the KEYLastName itself to the results ? so the resulting table would contain 3 fields,  KEYLastName, Year and CountOfOcurrances?

Comment: I am guessing you have many different KEYLastName containing the same year string, so you cannot simply add KEYLastName and Group on it. I have added a suggestion that may suit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the 4th and 5th characters in `KEYLastName` represent the last 2 digits of a year, so "FVS101209GO5" is for 2010.  If that is correct you can count the number of `KEYLastName` values which represent 2010 with either of these 2 queries:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf(Mid(KEYLastName, 4, 2) = "10", 1, 0)) AS occur
FROM MyTable;

SELECT Count(IIf(Mid(KEYLastName, 4, 2) = "10", 1, Null)) AS occur
FROM MyTable;
```

However, I'm unsure why you also have a `WHERE` clause to restrict the rows to those where `mydate` is from 2010.  If you want that, too, create an index on `mydate` and include this `WHERE` clause in one of the above queries.

```
WHERE mydate >= #2010-1-1# AND mydate < #2011-1-1#
```

With an index on `mydate` that should be much faster than asking the db engine to apply the `Year()` function to the `mydate` value from every row in the table.